# Unable to get a basic C++ program to compile on Cygwin on Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, g++, cygwin

I am new to Cygwin, Windows and C++, so please bear with me.

Here's the C++ program (try.cpp) I am trying to compile using Cygwin.

```
#include<iostream>
using namepsace std;

int main(void) {
        cout<<"Trying out CPP"<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Here's the version of Cygwin I am using (obtained using `uname -r` on the cygwin terminal) : `1.7.17(0.262/5/3)`

Here's the command I am using to compile my program:
    `g++ try.cpp`

Here are the errors I get:

```
$ g++ try.cpp
try.cpp:2: error: expected nested-name-specifier before "namepsace"
try.cpp:2: error: `namepsace' has not been declared
try.cpp:2: error: expected `;' before "std"
try.cpp:2: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
try.cpp: In function `int main()':
try.cpp:5: error: `cout' undeclared (first use this function)
try.cpp:5: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
try.cpp:5: error: `endl' undeclared (first use this function)
```

FWIW, here's what I get when I do `g++ -v` (version of the g++ installed on my computer, I presume)"

```
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/specs
Configured with: /managed/gcc-build/final-v3-bootstrap/gcc-3.4.4-999/configure --verbose --program-suffix=-3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,d,f77,pascal,java,objc --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --without-x --enable-libgcj --disable-java-awt --with-system-zlib --enable-interpreter --disable-libgcj-debug --enable-threads=posix --enable-java-gc=boehm --disable-win32-registry --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled/mistyped `namespace` as `namepsace`.

Comment: I want to shoot myself now !!! It compiled after I correct the typo, but now I am unable to get the executable to run. After `g++ -c try.cpp -o try.o` when I do `./try.o`, it says `-bash: ./try.o: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: You want something like `g++ -o try.exe try.cpp`. Right now, you're producing only an object file (`-c` means "compile but don't link"), and trying to execute that.

Comment: Man, I feel so stupid now. Anyway, thanks a lot for your timely help.